# Import THREE.js in node module adding variables or functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, three.js, export

I am trying to rewrite a THREE.js project that direct include JS files in HTML into a node module-based projects. Then using webpack to pack it into bundle.js, so that in HTML, it just includes bundle.js to execute.

**Original Project**

The source project struct looks like:

```
index.html
js/EVAOptions.js
js/EVAPreviews.js
js/EVALoader.js
js/OrbitControls.js
js/thee.min.js
```

index.html. The file key source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>EVA Visualizaion Project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
   <script src="js/EVAPreviews.js"></script>
   <script src="js/EVAOptions.js"></script>
   <script src="js/EVALoader.js"></script>

   <div id="workspace"></div>

   <script>
      // ...
      evaLoader = new THREE.EVALoader(onLoad, url, options);
      // ...
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

In the original project, after index.html includes three.min.js, it has a THREE object globally, thus any JS file could modify this THREE object.

As EVALoader.js did, it modify THREE object by appending a function.

EVALoader.js key source code:

```
THREE.EVALoader = function(onLoad, url, options){
    // todo something
}
```

There are many other JS files directly adding functions or variables into this THREE object.

**Target Project**

As the original project is complicated, I am trying to **minimize the modification** to original project first. I know this may not be a true module-based re-writing, but project-runnable first is a great motivation for me.

For THREE plugin or utils like OrbitControls.js is easy, it can be handled with

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
```

But for files like EVALoader.js. I am not knowing how to do with it.

What I am thinking is declaring a THREE object and export it. Can it works?

globals.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";
window.THREE = THREE;
export default THREE;
```

Then I can rewrite EVALoader.js

```
import * as THREE from "globals"

THREE.EVALoader = function(onLoad, url, options){
    // todo something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it by adding a file

```
globals.js

import * as MYTHREE from "three";

global.THREE = MYTHREE;
global.EVA= {};

console.log("start THREE", global.THREE);
console.log("start THREE", global.EVA);

export default MYTHREE;
```

Then import it and other js file.